# Persist url parameter throughout grails app

Tags: groovy, grails

Essentially I am looking to have a url query parameter persist throughout the life of the grails application (POST or GET). ex.

```
http://localhost:8080/demo/controller/action/?myParam=foobar
```

I have tried a couple routes. Dynamic method overriding **redirect** and customizing application tags for **createLink**. However, since I also use grails webflows it doesn't quite get every single URL. I also tried using a groovy servlet (**groovlet**) to capture every URL and append the query parameter. The last attempt hasn't been very successful. Am I missing an obvious component to grails? Am I on the right track? Is there another avenue I haven't explored yet?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why does this need to be a query parameter?  Why wouldn't you just store the value in the session?

Comment: Given the environment of where the grails war is being deployed there is a load balancer rule in place that requires the query parameter. This is something that I cannot change and therefore have to work with. The query parameter serves no purpose to the war only to please load balancer. Weird I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using a [filter](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.3.x/guide/single.html#6.6%20Filters)? The following filter will add the param to every request

```
class MyFilters {
   def filters = {
       addParam(controller:'*', action:'*') {
           before = {
               params.myParam = 'foobar'
           }

} } }
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing with an additional check to redirect. The redirect made sure the url always contained the query parameter it.